# What would mean "I heard him calling my name"

Tags: gerunds

I know we can  say " I heard him call my name" but in case this was happening all night long and continuously can we change call by calling .

Answer (score 2):

Basically yes, but to actually convey the meaning you intend to, it would be also required to switch the tense being used to Past Perfect Continuous:

> I have been hearing him calling my name [all night long].

Comment: but if I don't change the tense does it mean something "I heard him calling my name"